# Account record owner can see all assotiated opportunities

Tags: sharing

As far as I know there is lookup rel between Account & Opportunity. But why Account record owner can see all assotiated opportunities even oportunity record has another owner?
Quote from trailhead:
"Rose’s opportunity is also visible to Maya Pasqua, who owns the partner account within Salesforce."

Comment: Check you organization wide defaults and check the level of visibility you are granting your users for the Opportunity object. Perhaps they are public or depending on Parent relationship?

Comment: Opportunity has internal Public Read Only and external Private. But my question was why Account record owner can see related oportunities?

Comment: By the way, we are talking about Partner Account